# C# bitmap.save loses some pixels

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, pixel, loss

I writing a code to color my bitmap image pixels for

```
int[,] unClusteredImage = new int[367,158];
Bitmap clusteredImage = new Bitmap(367, 158);
for (int row = 0; row < unClusteredImage.GetLength(0); row++)
                        for (int col = 0; col < unClusteredImage.GetLength(1); col++)
                            if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 0)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Red);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 1)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Blue);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 2)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Green);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 3)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Yellow);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 4)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Black);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 5)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Orange);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 6)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Lime);
                            else if (unClusteredImage[row, col] == 7)
                                clusteredImage.SetPixel(row, col, Color.Purple);
clusteredImage.Save("test.jpeg");
```

The problem is that when i save the bitmap using the bitmap.save method I lose some pixels when I open it in paint I noticed that some pixels are not there in the bottom of my image

Comment: Which pixels do you lose?  Have you tried contacting the local Pixel authorities and had a search party?

Comment: You are not losing anything.  The entire image is always red because `unClusteredImage[row, col] == 0` is always zero.  Your rows and columns are reversed, too (at least by name).

Comment: no the entire image is not red. but when I open the image using paint I notice that the last few rows are missing with black.

Comment: Before you save the image you should draw it first to see if your code works ok. If the drawing produces the desired image then the save is the problem

Answer (score 3):

You are saving the image as JPEG.

JPG format is a lossy compressed file format. This makes it useful for storing photographs at a smaller size than a BMP.

PNG format is a lossless compression file format, which makes it a common choice for use in applications.

I suggest you try to save it in PNG Format, and check the result. And if you don't care about the size you can always save it as Bitmap.

```
clusteredImage.save("test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I tested your code it didn't work. same problem. I also tried the bitmap (bmp) didn't works as well. I can't upload an image to exaplain more due to reputations are not enough.

Comment: It fixed my issue... Thanks a lot!